# How to use an existing django database for another project

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I already have a project A which is live and now I want to create B which uses the same database of A and also the authentication can be interoperable. How can I accomplish that?
I created a app called core and in that I did python manage.py inspectdb it did give me all the models but I am not able to manage the auth for both the instances will I require to use the sites framework?

Comment: Although that *can* be achieved, typically you add different *apps* for that. Since otherwise you have to *rewrite* and *synchronize* models defined in the two projects.

Comment: I do understand that I have to synchronize but I will still want it do the hard way can you please suggest how to do that ?

Comment: Suggestion with: https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: @marin why sqlachemy when already using django ORM?